# Emploi du mot « kudos »

Tags: anglais, usage, grec

Peut-on employer couramment le mot *[kudos](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kudos)* en dehors de l'Internet remplaçant *bravo*, *félicitations*, etc. ? Par exemple :

> He deserves kudos for his promotion.
>
> Il mérite des félicitations pour sa promotion.

et

> Bravo à lui pour sa promotion.
>
> Il mérite des kudos pour sa promotion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Non, pas que je sache. Je ne l'ai jamais rencontré en français.

Comment: Moi non plus je ne l'ai jamais rencontré. J'ignorais même jusqu'à ce jour que l'origine était grecque. L'affirmation de Wikipédia selon laquelle _on peut donc désormais relever un usage du terme en français courant_ est grandement exagérée.

Answer (score -1):

A ma connaissance, "Kudos" est un mot qui se suffit à lui-même.
Tout comme "Félicitations" en français.

On m'a d'ailleurs attribué des Kudos sur mon profil Linkedin et j'ai en retour envoyé des Kudos en recommandation.

Difficile en revanche de l'employer à l'oral me semble-t-il, pour répondre à la question.

Comment: Non, Kudos n'est pas employé en français en dehors de l'internet, et ça celui qui a posé la question le sait déjà. FL n'est pas un forum de discussion mais un site de questions réponses où on attend des réponses aux questions posées.